# AngularFirebase2: Query list by month

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have below structure on Firebase:

```
- members
  -KkN7J3duEB0Lqz01S7v
      |- birthday: "1980-01-02"
```

and I'd like to query for members born in January no matter the year and day.

May I have the advice on how to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current structure doesn't allow for that type of query. As common with NoSQL databases you'll need to modify the data structure to allow the use-case you want:

```
- members
  -KkN7J3duEB0Lqz01S7v
      |- birthday: "1980-01-02"
      |- birthMonth: 1
```

Your query then becomes: `ref.child("members").orderByChild("birthMonth").equalTo(1)`.